# Unsupported relations for schema using GORM

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have two models:

```
type Customer struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name     string `gorm:"size:60;not null;index"`
    ClientID string `gorm:"size:21;not null;uniqueIndex"`
    Emails   []CustomerEmail
    Offers   []Offer `gorm:`
}

type CustomerEmail struct {
    gorm.Model
    Email       string `gorm:"size:100;not null"`
    PurposeType string `gorm:"size:25; not null"`
    CustomerID  uint
}
```

When I execute the following code:

```
customer := model.Customer{Name: "Test Customer",
        Emails: []model.CustomerEmail{
            {
                PurposeType: "standard",
                Email:       "test@test.com",
            },
            {
                PurposeType: "offers",
                Email:       "test2@test.com",
            },
        }}

    db.Debug().Preload("CustomerEmail").Where("name = ?", customer.Name).
        Attrs(&customer).FirstOrCreate(&customer)
```

I get the following error:

> CustomerEmail: unsupported relations for schema Customer [1.959ms]
> [rows:0] SELECT * FROM "customer" WHERE name = 'Test Customer' AND
> "customer"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "customer"."id" LIMIT 1
> Finished processing.

How do I resolve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I assumed that when using the 'Preload' method, you should pass in the name of the type.  The correct behavior is to pass in the name of the field that you wish to pre-load.  Please refer to the following:

Instead of this [name of CustomerEmail type]:

```
db.Debug().Preload("CustomerEmails").Where("name = ?", customer.Name).
    Attrs(&customer).FirstOrCreate(&customer)
```

You should specify this [Customer.Emails]:

```
db.Debug().Preload("Emails").Where("name = ?", customer.Name).
    Attrs(&customer).FirstOrCreate(&customer)
```